# C++ How to delete nodes in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, nodes, erase

So I have created a binary search tree that is stored within an array. This binary search tree (BST) stores a user input ID, Age, and Name, then places it within the array sorted in ascending order by the ID.

I'm attempting to write a delete function that takes a user input ID, loops through the vector, and if it finds a matching ID, it deletes it.

However, I can't seem to get BinaryTree.erase() to work due to an error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error (active)    E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::erase [with _Ty=Node,
>   _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list   Project_4CS210

After erasing, I plan on organizing the vector so that there aren't any open spots, however, I want to make sure that I can delete the node first. Any suggestions? I am a beginner, so most of this is rather new to me.

```
Here's my delete function. 


#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int index;

struct Node
{
    int ID;
    int age;
    string name;

    Node()
    {

    }

    Node(int id, int Age, string nm)
    {
        this->ID = id;
        this->age = Age;
        this->name = nm;
    }
};
vector<Node> binaryTree;
void BST::Delete()
{
    int input_id;
    cout << "What is the ID of the person to be deleted" << endl;
    cin >> input_id;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < binaryTree.size(); i++)
    {
if (input_id == binaryTree.at(i).ID)
        binaryTree.erase(i);



    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) does not take an `int` as parameter

Comment: You should be using the remove/erase idiom for this and stop trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: My question then is why you thought that *would* work, and which documentation indicated it would.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) takes an *iterator*, not an index.

You can use `binaryTree.begin() + i` to get the iterator for the i-th element of a vector (note that some containers have iterator types without `+`, so you'd need to use [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) there).

Overall, `binaryTree.erase(binaryTree.begin() + i)` should do the job you want, but for what you are trying to do you could also look into [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

To expand on this last point (because someone in the comments mentioned the remove/erase idiom):

```cpp
vector.erase(std::remove_if(vector.begin(), 
                            vector.end(),
                            [](const auto& element) { return condition(element); }),
             vector.end());
```

This will remove all elements from the vector where `condition(element)` returns `true`, and is generally better than iterating over the vector by hand:

- If you want to remove more than one element with your method, you might miss some. Take a vector where the elements you want to remove are at indices `i` and `i + 1`. Then, you remove the element at index `i` normally, and the element at `i + 1` moves to index `i` - however, in the next iteration you already check index `i + 1`, so you miss the item that you wanted to remove
- Each time you remove an element from the vector, all the elements behind that are moved around in memory. If your items are fairly big, that can be expensive. Using `remove_if` should ensure that each element isn't moved more than necessary, which can be more efficient especially if you remove many elements.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't remove elements from vector while iterating over it, you can miss some indexes while iterating, use `std::remove_if` to send elements needed to remove at the end of vector and then erase them from vector with `erase()` method:

```
auto It = std::remove_if(binaryTree.begin(), binaryTree.end(), [input](const Node& node)
         {
             if( node.ID == input )
             {
                 return true;
             }
             return false;

         });
binaryTree.erase(It,binaryTree.end());
```

Method `erase()` accepts iterators to remove range or one iterator to remove one element. `std::remove_if` will return iterator for the first elements pushed at the end to remove.

Comment: It's very much possible to remove elements from a vector if you are iterating over the size of the vector like he is instead of using iterators (or ranged-for loops)

Comment: @hlt Yes you are right thanks for comment, I have improved answer and add some more explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you wish to remove all the items in the vector or a specific item. You can actually erase items from a vector using `erase` while iterating. Keep in mind the `erase` actually provides you with the iterator to the next item. So you may not need to increment the iterator unless it fulfills the condition.

Here is a sample code:

```
for (std::vector<Node>::iterator it =  binaryTree.begin(); it != binaryTree.end();)
{
    if(it == yourItem) //Conditional check if it matches with your object.
    {
       it =  binaryTree.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
       ++it;
    }
}
```

You can see that i am actually getting the iterator to the next item in the list without incrementing it. You can process it in whatever way you may like.